# How to patch Abiword in XUbuntu

Tags: xubuntu, abiword

I'm a developer migrating to linux from mac. Just installed XUbuntu on my new ASUS 1015E and I'm seeing the scrolling bug in Abiword that seems to be a pretty common problem. However, like this user:

https://askubuntu.com/q/206381/175684

...I'm brand new to linux and I can't figure out how to patch it. Here's the link to the bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/960089

Could someone please direct me to how to install the patch OR downgrade to Abiword 2.8.6? (the software center doesn't seem to offer a downgrade, and I tried installing according to these instructions:

http://abisource.com/wiki/Install_on_Ubuntu

but still got 2.9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Lovely little blog post right here:

http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-downgrade-abiword-version-to-286.html

You start from having version 2.9.2 installed, then you just run this one big long command from the terminal to download xubuntugeek's script, uninstall the old version, install the new one, and it even cleans up the script for you :).

```
cd && wget -O downgrade_abiword.sh http://goo.gl/cZM6N && chmod +x downgrade_abiword.sh && ./downgrade_abiword.sh && rm downgrade_abiword.sh
```